# Facebook Automatic Embedded Posts On Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, facebook, facebook-graph-api

i would like to embed each post from my facebook page to the specified wordpress post using the new facebook code like this: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/embedded-posts

The problem is that iam looking for an automated way to do it since the are more than 100 posts on my website. Like a link that detects each post on my facebook page..

Any help? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you get a solution yet?

Comment: no, iam still looking...